# Get a list of maven dependencies excluding test dependencies

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I would like to get a list of all dependencies for my maven project but without the test dependencies using Maven 3.6.2.

To list all of the dependencies I've used `dependency:tree` or `dependency:list` successfully.

I've then tried adding `-DincludeScope=compile` and `-DexcludeScope=test` as arguments. With these added I still get test dependencies included.

**Example command**

```
mvn -f example/location/pom.xml dependency:tree -DincludeScope=compile -DexcludeScope=test
```

**Output**

```
...
...
...
 \- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
    \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
```

**Parent dependency is test and child is compile**

I've also found another issue. If a parent dependency is `test` then I don't want to see any of its dependencies.

```
...
...
|  +- com.google.cloud:google-cloud-core-grpc:jar:1.52.0:test
|  |  +- com.google.auth:google-auth-library-credentials:jar:0.11.0:compile
```

How do I remove all test dependencies and their children?

Comment: This bug seems related:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSHARED-4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`includeScope` and `excludeScope` are not a parameters of [`dependency:tree` Mojo](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) so they will have no effect. Depending on your `maven-plugin-dependency` version `scope` parameter might work (see [MSHARED-4](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSHARED-4)):

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dscope=compile
```

Comment: I don't think it will be possible the way you've mentioned. If the parent dependency is `test` and its child is `compile`, I don't want to include it. I've updated my question to show this. 
The only way I can see it being done (If it's not possible with particular arguments to maven) is to find out the indentation of the output. If the parent is a test then remove all of its children. It wouldn't be very nice to do though.

Comment: Removed `grep` suggestion, it won't work in your setup with transitive dependencies between scopes.